# Python unit test failing with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pytest, aws-sam, python-3.10

I have created a lambda function using AWS-SAM python.

I am trying to run the unit test here. I haven't changed any files in unit test but trying to run it.

Steps I followed:

```
pip install -r tests/requirements.txt --user
python -m pytest tests/unit -v
```

This generate below error:

```
from hello_world import app
hello_world\app.py:3: in <module>
    from response import Response
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'response'***
```

My `app.py` has below import

```
from response import Response
```

Which is a simple class

```
class Response:
    def __init__(self, message, resp_type):
        self.message = message
        self.resp_type = resp_type
```

Project structure as below

```
Project-Name
 -.aws-sam
 - events
 - hello_world
 - tests
   - integration
   - unit
       - __init__.py
       - test_handler.py
   - __init__.py
   - requirements.txt
```

Comment: What do you have in tests/requirements.txt? I guess you have the "response" library? And another thing, why is requirements.txt inside the "tests" folder? Requirements are not something only for testing purposes, it is also to just run the project. I would recommend having "hello_world" folder inside the "src" folder, which prevents that the package source folder gets imported instead of the installed package.

Comment: @Asi: `Response` is a class sitting in `hello_world` folder. its no a package. And your question *why is requirements.txt inside the "tests" folder* its come by default from template. its to run tests stuff like pytest etc.. there is another   requirements.txt inside `hello_world` folder which needs to run the project

Comment: You are using the `Response` class from `response` library here: `from response import Response`. And the error you are facing is about that library: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'response'`

Comment: @Asi its not a library. it just a simple class with couple of fields. I have updated the question with that class

Comment: What file contains that class?  The Python interpreter cannot find it.  Believe the interpreter.

Comment: @duffymo. its a response.py file. sits under `hello_world` folder

Comment: That's one level above your test_interpreter.py.  Shouldn't you use ../ to get up to that directory?